# How to plot/extract the BIC values from the step function

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I need to plot the BIC value from each regression step in the step function using ggplot. I have no idea how to use ggplot to plot each steps BIC value.

```
form_model <- formula(lm(price~sqft_living+sqft_lot+waterfront+sqft_above+sqft_basement+years_since_renovations+age_of_house+grade_int+bed_int+bath_int+floors_dummy+view_dummy+condition_dummy+basement_dummy+renovated_dummy+weekend_dummy))
mod <- lm(price~1)
n <- (nrow(House_Regr))
forwardBIC <- step(mod,form_model,direction = "forward", k=log(n) )
```

Here is the model that i am using.

```
Start:  AIC=181611.1
price ~ 1

                          Df  Sum of Sq        RSS    AIC
+ sqft_living              1 5.5908e+16 6.9104e+16 178111
+ grade_int                1 4.2600e+16 8.2413e+16 179154
+ sqft_above               1 3.8988e+16 8.6024e+16 179407
+ view_dummy               1 1.5755e+16 1.0926e+17 180822
+ sqft_basement            1 1.1560e+16 1.1345e+17 181045
+ bed_int                  1 1.0586e+16 1.1443e+17 181096
+ floors_dummy             1 8.6756e+15 1.1634e+17 181194
+ waterfront               1 8.1097e+15 1.1690e+17 181223
+ basement_dummy           1 3.8336e+15 1.2118e+17 181435
+ bath_int                 1 2.1104e+15 1.2290e+17 181519
+ renovated_dummy          1 1.3665e+15 1.2365e+17 181555
+ years_since_renovations  1 8.6785e+14 1.2414e+17 181579
+ sqft_lot                 1 8.2901e+14 1.2418e+17 181580
+ condition_dummy          1 6.4654e+14 1.2437e+17 181589
<none>                                  1.2501e+17 181611
+ age_of_house             1 1.7600e+14 1.2484e+17 181611
+ weekend_dummy            1 9.3267e+11 1.2501e+17 181620

Step:  AIC=178111
price ~ sqft_living

                          Df  Sum of Sq        RSS    AIC
+ view_dummy               1 4.7046e+15 6.4399e+16 177702
+ age_of_house             1 4.5059e+15 6.4598e+16 177721
+ waterfront               1 4.3957e+15 6.4708e+16 177731
+ grade_int                1 3.1890e+15 6.5915e+16 177840
+ years_since_renovations  1 3.0576e+15 6.6046e+16 177852
+ bed_int                  1 1.7778e+15 6.7326e+16 177965
+ bath_int                 1 1.7527e+15 6.7351e+16 177968
+ renovated_dummy          1 7.2312e+14 6.8381e+16 178057
+ basement_dummy           1 3.1144e+14 6.8793e+16 178093
+ sqft_above               1 1.6922e+14 6.8935e+16 178105
+ sqft_basement            1 1.6922e+14 6.8935e+16 178105
+ sqft_lot                 1 1.2746e+14 6.8977e+16 178109
<none>                                  6.9104e+16 178111
+ condition_dummy          1 3.6244e+13 6.9068e+16 178117
+ floors_dummy             1 1.0259e+13 6.9094e+16 178119
+ weekend_dummy            1 5.9534e+12 6.9098e+16 178119
```

Here is a small output from the regression. I need to plot each steps BIC value using ggplot. My idea would be to just extract the BIC value for each step then plot them using ggplot but as i have said i have no idea how to accomplish this or if extracting the BIC is even necessary for ggplot.

How would i go about plotting the BIC for each step in the regression on ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this usually, so if there is an answer using real functions then go for it. There is a function called in this: `extractAIC` that is storing the results, and then printing those tables. You can get the `step` function by typing it in the console. Quick scan showed me that in the variable `aod` inside this function it is storing the tables that it prints for each iteration.

A hacky way is to make a list inside this function, update the list with the table each time it changes and then either add it to the response (the usual way) or assign it out to the global environment (bad way). As I don't know anything about the class of the response of the step function, I've opted for the bad way. The full function is here. You can search for the `# (!) addition` flag to see where I've added it in.

The AIC column contains the BIC values. You can see it changes when you change the `k` value in the `step` call

Hope this works ok for you, I'm using the example in the `step` function

```
step2 <- function (object, scope, scale = 0, direction = c("both", "backward", 
                                                  "forward"), trace = 1, keep = NULL, steps = 1000, k = 2, 
          ...) 
{

  # (!) addition
  aod.all <- list()

  mydeviance <- function(x, ...) {
    dev <- deviance(x)
    if (!is.null(dev)) 
      dev
    else extractAIC(x, k = 0)[2L]
  }
  cut.string <- function(string) {
    if (length(string) > 1L) 
      string[-1L] <- paste0("\n", string[-1L])
    string
  }
  re.arrange <- function(keep) {
    namr <- names(k1 <- keep[[1L]])
    namc <- names(keep)
    nc <- length(keep)
    nr <- length(k1)
    array(unlist(keep, recursive = FALSE), c(nr, nc), list(namr, 
                                                           namc))
  }
  step.results <- function(models, fit, object, usingCp = FALSE) {
    change <- sapply(models, "[[", "change")
    rd <- sapply(models, "[[", "deviance")
    dd <- c(NA, abs(diff(rd)))
    rdf <- sapply(models, "[[", "df.resid")
    ddf <- c(NA, diff(rdf))
    AIC <- sapply(models, "[[", "AIC")
    heading <- c("Stepwise Model Path \nAnalysis of Deviance Table", 
                 "\nInitial Model:", deparse(formula(object)), "\nFinal Model:", 
                 deparse(formula(fit)), "\n")
    aod <- data.frame(Step = I(change), Df = ddf, Deviance = dd, 
                      `Resid. Df` = rdf, `Resid. Dev` = rd, AIC = AIC, 
                      check.names = FALSE)
    if (usingCp) {
      cn <- colnames(aod)
      cn[cn == "AIC"] <- "Cp"
      colnames(aod) <- cn
    }
    attr(aod, "heading") <- heading
    fit$anova <- aod
    fit
  }
  Terms <- terms(object)
  object$call$formula <- object$formula <- Terms
  md <- missing(direction)
  direction <- match.arg(direction)
  backward <- direction == "both" | direction == "backward"
  forward <- direction == "both" | direction == "forward"
  if (missing(scope)) {
    fdrop <- numeric()
    fadd <- attr(Terms, "factors")
    if (md) 
      forward <- FALSE
  }
  else {
    if (is.list(scope)) {
      fdrop <- if (!is.null(fdrop <- scope$lower)) 
        attr(terms(update.formula(object, fdrop)), "factors")
      else numeric()
      fadd <- if (!is.null(fadd <- scope$upper)) 
        attr(terms(update.formula(object, fadd)), "factors")
    }
    else {
      fadd <- if (!is.null(fadd <- scope)) 
        attr(terms(update.formula(object, scope)), "factors")
      fdrop <- numeric()
    }
  }
  models <- vector("list", steps)
  if (!is.null(keep)) 
    keep.list <- vector("list", steps)
  n <- nobs(object, use.fallback = TRUE)
  fit <- object
  bAIC <- extractAIC(fit, scale, k = k, ...)
  edf <- bAIC[1L]
  bAIC <- bAIC[2L]
  if (is.na(bAIC)) 
    stop("AIC is not defined for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed")
  if (bAIC == -Inf) 
    stop("AIC is -infinity for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed")
  nm <- 1
  if (trace) {
    cat("Start:  AIC=", format(round(bAIC, 2)), "\n", cut.string(deparse(formula(fit))), 
        "\n\n", sep = "")
    flush.console()
  }
  models[[nm]] <- list(deviance = mydeviance(fit), df.resid = n - 
                         edf, change = "", AIC = bAIC)
  if (!is.null(keep)) 
    keep.list[[nm]] <- keep(fit, bAIC)
  usingCp <- FALSE
  while (steps > 0) {
    steps <- steps - 1
    AIC <- bAIC
    ffac <- attr(Terms, "factors")
    scope <- factor.scope(ffac, list(add = fadd, drop = fdrop))
    aod <- NULL
    change <- NULL
    if (backward && length(scope$drop)) {
      aod <- drop1(fit, scope$drop, scale = scale, trace = trace, 
                   k = k, ...)
      rn <- row.names(aod)
      row.names(aod) <- c(rn[1L], paste("-", rn[-1L]))
      if (any(aod$Df == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
        zdf <- aod$Df == 0 & !is.na(aod$Df)
        change <- rev(rownames(aod)[zdf])[1L]
      }
    }
    if (is.null(change)) {
      if (forward && length(scope$add)) {
        aodf <- add1(fit, scope$add, scale = scale, trace = trace, 
                     k = k, ...)
        rn <- row.names(aodf)
        row.names(aodf) <- c(rn[1L], paste("+", rn[-1L]))
        aod <- if (is.null(aod)) 
          aodf
        else rbind(aod, aodf[-1, , drop = FALSE])
      }
      attr(aod, "heading") <- NULL
      nzdf <- if (!is.null(aod$Df)) 
        aod$Df != 0 | is.na(aod$Df)
      aod <- aod[nzdf, ]
      if (is.null(aod) || ncol(aod) == 0) 
        break
      nc <- match(c("Cp", "AIC"), names(aod))
      nc <- nc[!is.na(nc)][1L]
      o <- order(aod[, nc])

      # (!) addition
      aod.all <- c(aod.all, list(aod))

      if (trace) 
        print(aod[o, ])
      if (o[1L] == 1) 
        break
      change <- rownames(aod)[o[1L]]
    }
    usingCp <- match("Cp", names(aod), 0L) > 0L
    fit <- update(fit, paste("~ .", change), evaluate = FALSE)
    fit <- eval.parent(fit)
    nnew <- nobs(fit, use.fallback = TRUE)
    if (all(is.finite(c(n, nnew))) && nnew != n) 
      stop("number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?")
    Terms <- terms(fit)
    bAIC <- extractAIC(fit, scale, k = k, ...)
    edf <- bAIC[1L]
    bAIC <- bAIC[2L]
    if (trace) {
      cat("\nStep:  AIC=", format(round(bAIC, 2)), "\n", 
          cut.string(deparse(formula(fit))), "\n\n", sep = "")
      flush.console()
    }
    if (bAIC >= AIC + 1e-07) 
      break
    nm <- nm + 1
    models[[nm]] <- list(deviance = mydeviance(fit), df.resid = n - 
                           edf, change = change, AIC = bAIC)
    if (!is.null(keep)) 
      keep.list[[nm]] <- keep(fit, bAIC)
  }
  if (!is.null(keep)) 
    fit$keep <- re.arrange(keep.list[seq(nm)])

  # (!) addition
  assign("aod.all", aod.all, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  step.results(models = models[seq(nm)], fit, object, usingCp)
}

lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
slm1 <- step2(lm1)
aod.all
```